# Uso de la etiqueta <meter>

Tags: html5

Buen día
Tengo dudas acerca del uso de la etiqueta meter de html5 ya que la estoy empleando en un proyecto pero no me da los resultados esperados, tal vez la este implementando mal... pongo el siguiente ejemplo

```html
<meter value="6" low="3" max="6">2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter value="6" low="4" max="6">2 out of 10</meter><br>
```

mi duda es por que al ejecutar el código una barra es de color verde y la otra es amarilla si en los dos casos el valor del "value" no esta dentro del rango del atributo "min" que se configura por defecto en 0, y el "low" que en los dos casos es menor al value?

Answer (score 6):

```html
<meter value="6" low="2" max="6">2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter value="6" low="3" max="6">2 out of 10</meter><br>

<br>
<br>

Es un error de jerarquía, toma la siguiente guía
debes hacerlo asi

<!-- min <= low <= value <= high <= max -->

<br><br>


<meter  min="1" low ="1" value ="1" high ="6" max="6"        >2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter  min="1" low ="1" value ="2" high ="6" max="6"        >2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter  min="1" low ="1" value ="3" high ="6" max="6"        >2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter  min="1" low ="1" value ="4" high ="6" max="6"        >2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter  min="1" low ="1" value ="5" high ="6" max="6"        >2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter  min="1" low ="1" value ="6" high ="6" max="6"        >2 out of 10</meter><br>
```

sin salir de los valores minimos o maximos

Comment: puedes ver mas aqui
https://www.anerbarrena.com/etiqueta-meter-html5-4819/

Comment: si se aplico la respuesta recuerda marcarla como correcta

Answer (score 3):

esto se da porque `<meter><meter>` fue dise;ado para las estadistica de uso:
como medida de consumo de CPU,memoria,spacio etc...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen podemos ver como lo optimo esta al medio ya que `optimum` esta en `50` que es la mitada ni muy bajo ni muy alto
en tu caso el `low="4"` de un rango `max="6"` y un `value="6"` asi que toma como zona baja o no optima de `4` en adelante y omite el `high=""` dejando solo 2 zonas baja y optima como `0` a `3` porque por defecto `min="0"`

```html
<meter value="1" low="4" max="6">2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter value="3" low="4" max="6">2 out of 10</meter><br>
<meter value="6" low="4" max="6">2 out of 10</meter><br>
```

ahora bien tambien podemos especificarle rango altos, bajos y optimos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<p>28% <meter min="0" max="100" low="34" high="70"  optimum="90" value="28"></meter> VENTAS<br>
40% <meter min="0" max="100" low="34" high="70"  optimum="90" value="40"></meter> PRUEBAS<br>
80% <meter min="0" max="100" low="34" high="70"  optimum="90" value="80"></meter> CODIGO<br></p>
```

1. donde `min` es el valor minimo y `max` es el valor maximo para
   nuestra barra
2. `optimum` es para elegir nuestra zona `segura` reprensentada de color `verde`.
3. `low` y `high` es para especificar los rangos posible.
4. todo por debajo de `low` o arriba de `high` se considerara como zona demaciado `baja` o `alta` dependiendo del valor de `optimun` entre mas lejos mas `peligro`.

ahora podemos hacer un ejemplo del consumo de nuestro equipo **invirtiendo el valor optimun**:

```html
<p>28% <meter min="0" max="100" low="50" high="80"  optimum="0" value="28"></meter> DISCO<br>
60% <meter min="0" max="100" low="50" high="80"  optimum="0" value="60"></meter> MEMORIA<br>
90% <meter min="0" max="100" low="50" high="80"  optimum="0" value="90"></meter> CPU<br><p>
```

**referencia:**
[HTML5 Meter](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/style-html5-meter/)

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que si no especificás el valor óptimo (con el atributo `optimum`), éste se se fija exactamente a mitad de camino entre `min` y `max` (o sea 3).

Ahora, si el valor óptimo está entre `low` y `high` (primer caso), entonces si el valor está también entre `low` y `high`, la barra se pinta de verde. Y si está fuera de ese rango, de amarillo.

Pero si el valor óptimo es menor a `low` (segundo caso), entonces si el valor está entre 0 y `low`, la barra se pone verde, si está entre `low` y `high` se pone amarilla (lo que pasa en ese caso), y si es mayor a `high` se pone roja.

Lo mismo ocurre cuando el valor óptimo es mayor a `high` (pero para el otro lado, por supuesto).